# Update Hyper-V Server 2012 (free version) to r2

Tags: update, hyper-v-server-2012

Is there any way to patch Hyper-V Server 2012 to Hyper-V Server 2012 R2? 
Or I need to download & install new version instead with manual VM migration?

I tried to google it, but found answers only about Windows Server 2012 with Hyper-V component.

Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyper-V Server 2012 and Hyper-V Server 2012 R2 are two distinctly different products. You cannot ***update*** from one to the other. You can ***upgrade*** from one to the other.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn303416.aspx

Comment: And what about upgrading process? Do I need to stop VMs and then just start them? Do I need to change something in VMs to migrate them correctly, or R2 will work with them _by default_.